# Where can I find citeable material on radiation shielding solutions utilized on different test missions?

Tags: cubesat, radiation, reference-request, shielding, protection

I'm having a hard time finding citeable material on what different radiation shielding solutions different test missions have utilized.

So far I've found that:

- SpectroCube only shields its most sensitive electronics with 6mm aluminium
- GTOSat has a radiation vault and spot shielding
- Orbital Factory 2 has an aluminium case
- Shields-1 compares the performance of different kinds of radiation shields

However, all of these missions are to GTO (or HEO, higher erth orbits). It would be nice to find some material on missions to lower earth orbits. I can't find any reflection on the used solutions either. E.g. whether the shield was thick enough or not, if it was unnecessary and so on.

Answer (score 1):

A search on NASA NTRS turns up over 15,000 results.  Perhaps some of those are relevant?

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search?q=radiation%20shielding